# Static Website Generators in MVC3 or ASP.NET in general

Tags: asp.net, web, generator

I see a lot of projects in other languages for generating static web sites from dynamic engines.  Things like Frank, Jekyll, Hyde, Webby and Poole.

There is a large list here:

http://iwantmyname.com/blog/2011/02/list-static-website-generators.html

But I can't seem to find anything in the .NET space.

I find it an interesting angle of combining performance and usability on relatively static content like blogs.

But I can also see this as a great HTML based help generation system.  And I don't mean API documentation, for which there seems to be a hundred projects.  I mean actual application documentation or other documentation.

So, any great static website generators in the .NET space?

Comment: Hmmmm, just found Nancy  https://github.com/thecodejunkie/Nancy  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nevermind.  Nancy is lightweight, but doesn't appear to be used to generate static content.  So still looking

Comment: I would have thought the static HTML generator would not have any awareness of the server side technology? Wouldn't it simply read each page in your dynamic site and save it as static HTML?

Comment: Sure.  Using some of the above mentioned frameworks, Sinatra is a light-weight web framework in the Ruby space.  Frank is a Ruby static website generator based on the ideas in Sinatra.  It looks like it has similar concepts as Frank but also has export commands for saving to static html & css, and publish commands for uploading your website.  Having these commands be robust is essential, since you are basically using a dynamic engine on your desk to periodically update your static data in the cloud.

Comment: One of the biggest advantages is that you are using the same tools and frameworks that you already know and love.  So, I figured there must be people doing this in the .NET space with things like MVC3.  Or, since Nancy looks like it was inspired by Frank, maybe a fork of Frank would be the natural progression?

Comment: I mean a fork of Nancy.  Also found Jessica, which looks to be inspired by Frank as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively recent development is the 52 code project [Pretzel](http://code52.org/pretzel.html) - a .Net static code generator. It is worth a look if you know Jekyll.

Comment: Still seems like it's an early work in progress.  But it's the first real attempt I've seen in the space.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for completeness I'll add http://wyam.io (open source - code at https://github.com/Wyamio/Wyam). It uses a modified version of the Razor engine from ASP.NET v5 for templating and also has support for Markdown. It's built on a modular "pipeline" concept (similar to the excellent Metalsmith JavaScript-based site generator) and is easy to extend given that the configuration files are dynamically compiled with Roslyn.

Full disclosure - I am the developer of Wyam.

Answer (score 2):

Graze is a possible option too!

https://github.com/mikoskinen/graze